# (Mojave 10.4.2) Missing top right items (clock, network, battery etc.)

Tags: macos, mojave

I don't know what happened. I restarted mac and since then I don't have top right icons: network, sound, battery, clock, notification but from time to time it blink and for a moment become visible but immediately disappear.
I tried (and with sudo):

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

I restarted mac and still same.
Is there any way that I can reset this icons settings?
And I repeat wired thing is that it blink as I move cursor and from time to time for a moment I see items.
And also skype, dropbox and spotlight icons are always there.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is suggested:

1. Navigate to the *Library* folder in Finder

> - Open Finder
> - Use *Go* -> *Go to Folder*  (Shortcut: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
> - Type `~/Library` and hit Go

[image: Go to the folder menu]

2. From the *Library*, navigate to the *Preferences* folder.

   - Locate and remove the file named **com.apple.systemuiserver.plist**

[image: Library - Preferences in Finder]

3. Navigate to the folder *ByHost* which is inside the *Preferences* folder.

   - Locate and remove the file(s) named **com.apple.systemuiserver.[random_number].plist**
4. Restart your computer.

*SystemUIServers handles .menu software amongst other things, and thus this is expected to resolve your issue.*

Comment: I don't have `com.apple.systemuiserver.plist` in that folder.
Also there is no ByHost folder.

Comment: First, look for the file in `~/Library` instead

Alternatively, (1) Reboot into Safe Mode, and back again. (2) Recover/restore the *com.apple.systemuiserver.plist* from a Time Machine backup. (3) See if the file appears when using
`ls -lO ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.s*.plist`

Comment: See [Ask Different - Com.apple.finder.plist is missing and isn't being made automatically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221506/com-apple-finder-plist-is-missing-and-isnt-being-made-automatically) for additional info. Remember the tilde in `~/Library`.

Comment: I tried and didn't work. I boot into safe mode and issue is there in safe mode too. I restarted still same. When I enter that command it is listed. I deleted files from ~/Library I don't know what is this

Comment: Just to clarify, you followed my initial guide and navigated to `~/Library/Preferences` and removed **com.apple.systemuiserver.plist**, and then navigated to `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost` and removed **com.apple.systemuiserver.[random_number].plist**, before restarting? After removing the files and restarting the issue still persisted?

Comment: Yes. I did all that restarted problem was still there. Then I reboot to safe mode and restart and everything same. When I am on user pick screen items are there but when login they disappear (all users).

Comment: That makes sense. The issue is indeed related to your User. I recommend performing the same steps of deleting com.apple.systemuiserverr files in Preferences and ByHost as already mentioned, but then killing the process (perhaps multiple times) instead of restarting with `sudo killall -9 SystemUIServer`.

Comment: If the issue still persists, perhaps the following resources can be of any assistance: [Apple Discussions - Menu Bar Icons Missing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4155648?page=3), [Apple Discussions - Icons in Menu Bar disappearing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6634325?page=1) and [Ask Different - Icons disappearing from menu bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157060/icons-disappearing-from-menu-bar)

Comment: Additionally, It could be that a single application is causing the trouble. One can attempt to terminate probable applications before performing the `sudo killall -9 SystemUIServer` command.